# FPS increase while holding any mouse button

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse, framerate

I have a problem. Normally when I'm playing CS:GO I have ~30 FPS. But recently I realized, that when I'm holding any mouse button (mouse1 - mouse5) my FPS suddenly increases to ~70. One more thing - when I go out of the game and back (Alt+Tab) the increase doesn't work anymore. But when I respawn ingame, it does work again. So the problem should be some incompatibility between my mouse and CS:GO. When I don't hold any mouse button, my FPS simply goes down to 30.

I tried to change mice of course, but the result was the same - holding mouse button increases FPS. Note that this doesn't happen in any other game.

Thanks for your reply, hope to get 60 FPS avg, that would be great.

System information:

[image]

My CS:GO binds file:

```
echo "**Custom Binds                     Loaded**"
bind "MOUSE1" "+attack"
bind "mwheelup" "+jump"
bind "mwheeldown" "+jump"
alias "+jumpthrow" "+jump;+attack;-attack;-attack2"
alias "-jumpthrow" "-jump"
bind "mouse3" "+jumpthrow"
bindtoggle "mouse4" "cl_righthand"
bind "mouse5" "+voicerecord"
bind "mouse2" "+attack2"
```

Comment: So now we shall guess what your PC Specs are and what mouse you have? Or you going to add it?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness The problem isn't caused by low PC specs nor mouse. I said, I tried to change mice (Logitech, connectIT....), but it still does the same. But I'll add these specs if you need it, just wait a minute

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness here you are http://prntscr.com/71i4ex + 4GB RAM

Comment: Put your information in the post. And no, a screenshot is not cutting it. Whenever you ask for help about technical stuff, it is always required to tell people what you are using. Otherwise it is a guessing game. And yes, it does have something to do with your specs. They are important.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Low rep users can't post pictures. With your rep count, you should've done something to help him out there.

Comment: @Kazarp Do you have any other functions binded to M1?  Anything besides Primary Fire?

Comment: @hotlinecalifornia no, I added all my mouse binds to the question. You can see there is simply +attack on m1. Besides, the FPS boost happens when holding any mouse button m1-m5. And it doesn't work while rolling mouse wheel

Comment: What happens if: a) you disable "adaptive vsync" in driver settings or; b) force your CPU to always run at 100% frequency (test either/each/both)

Comment: @Yorik same thing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note that I'm the author of this question**

So I just reinstalled my Windows 8.1. I wanted to try CS:GO on Linux, if the same thing happens there, but my dual-boot was broken and the result -

> Missing operating system...

So I installed Windows 8.1 back and downloaded Steam and CS:GO, nothing more. Now CS:GO runs permanently on ~60-70 FPS while playing, no problems anymore. **I thing the problem was with my mouse driver**, because I updated it recently with some driver-updating software.

So the problem is solved. If you have the same problem, try to restore your drivers or check your PC for a virus

Answer (score -1):

Go into your graphics settings and disable vsync, Vsync usualy limits a game to either 30 or 60fps depending on machine performance to reduce screen tearing. This should also increase your fps alot

Comment: I have vsync always disabled, so this isn't it